# Database diagram on .net core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

On a .NET application we could auto generate .edmx file from database and can see its diagram by double clicking on that .edmx file. Now my question is since .NET Core does not allow to generate .edmx file then how i can see database diagram visually like the picture bellow? Is there any valid way to do it on .NET Core?

[image: pic]

Comment: Short answer: no, there's none currently. Unless of course you are working with SQL Server and use SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: This isn't a database diagram, it's a class diagram.

Comment: Whats the diff between class diagram and class diagram? Both represent same isn't it? @Gert

Answer (score 1):

> Whats the diff between class diagram and database diagram?

Technically that's a diagram of your Conceptual Model, the Edmx file contains the Conceptual Model, and explicit mapping metadata to map the Conceptual Model to a Storage Model on one side, and an Object Model on the other side.  EF has since moved away from the explicit mapping in the .Edmx and uses a combination of Conventions, Fluent Configuration and Class Annotations to generate the mapping at runtime.  This is called "Code First", although in practice you often generate a "Code First" model from an existing Database.

In EF6 Code First the Conceptual Model and Storage Model still technically exist, they are just generated at runtime from your Object Model.  In EF Core one of the main design goals was to remove the limitations and complexity of this older 3-Model design, and the Conceptual Model (which is what the design surface of an EDMX displays) is gone altogether.  No Conceptual Model, no .Edmx, no graphical designer.